# Generate a score for several row and certain values and sum all

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case-when

I have a table as below

```
    CustomerNumber  CustomerName    Type    Gender  Age Nationality Residance
    584             John Denver     Retail  Male    50  English     Domestic
    137             Jennifer Hazel  Retail  Female  34  Jamaican    Abroad
    547             Daniel Gorbo    Retail  Male    78  French      Domestic
```

I need to generate a total score depends on Type, Gender, Age, Nationality and Residance values. For example,

- For gender, male value generates "1", female "0"
- For age, if it is greater than 65 generates "3" else "0"
- For Nationality if non-english than generate 2 else 0

Final table should look like this:

```
    CustomerNumber  CustomerName    Type    Gender  Age Nationality Residance   RiskScore
    584             John Denver     Retail  Male    50  English     Domestic    1
    137             Jennifer Hazel  Retail  Female  34  Jamaican    Abroad      2
    547             Daniel Gorbo    Retail  Male    78  French      Domestic    6
```

I tried to add sum and 'case when' to main code however i got the error of 'need group by function'

```
sum( case when gender = 'Male' then 1 
        when age>65 then 3 
        when nationality = 'Abroad' then 2 else 0 end ) as RiskScore
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Why the `RiskScore` for `CustomerNumber` 584  is `3`?

Comment: 584 is male (1) and French (non-english=2)

Comment: I see, but please, fix the table row `584             John Denver     Retail  Male    50  English     Domestic` and the expected result `584             John Denver     Retail  Male    50  French      Domestic    3`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you do not need an aggregation. Use an addition and `CASE` expression to calculate the risk score:

```
SELECT 
   v.*,
   RiskScore = (
      CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN Age > 65 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN Nationality <> 'English' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
   )
FROM (VALUES
   (584, 'John Denver',    'Retail', 'Male',   50, 'French',   'Domestic'),
   (137, 'Jennifer Hazel', 'Retail', 'Female', 34, 'Jamaican', 'Abroad'),
   (547, 'Daniel Gorbo',   'Retail', 'Male',   78, 'English',  'Domestic')
) v (CustomerNumber, CustomerName, Type, Gender, Age, Nationality, Residance)
```

Result:

```
CustomerNumber CustomerName   Type   Gender Age Nationality Residance RiskScore
584            John Denver    Retail Male   50  French      Domestic  3
137            Jennifer Hazel Retail Female 34  Jamaican    Abroad    2
547            Daniel Gorbo   Retail Male   78  English     Domestic  4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *,
(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end  + 
case when    age>65 then 3 else 0 end + 
case when nationality <> 'English' 
then 2 else 0 end)  as risk_score from my_table;
```

Just change your condition accordingly

Answer (score 1):

As per the logic shared by you, below query should give the correct result using CASE and adding the value without group by:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f51c8/7)

```
SELECT A.*,  COALESCE(case when gender = 'Male' then 1  ELSE 0 END , 0) +
        COALESCE(CASE WHEN  age>65 then 3 ELSE 0 END , 0) +
        COALESCE( CASE when Nationality  <> 'English' then 2 else 0 end, 0 ) as RiskScore 
        FROM TABLE1 A;
```